# How to read ERESOLVE in npm audit fix?

Tags: npm

Here is the output I have after getting audit warnings after installing an npm package:

```
$ npm audit fix
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@21.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.46.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.46.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-unused-imports@2.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-unused-imports
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-unused-imports@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.1" from eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@21.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@"^21.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.33.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.1" from eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@21.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@"^21.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/lancepollard/.npm/_logs/2023-01-02T17_19_47_490Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lancepollard/.npm/_logs/2023-01-02T17_19_47_490Z-debug-0.log
```

That came after running `npm audit fix --force` a few times, after getting this:

```
$ npm install eslint-plugin-unused-imports --save-dev


added 2 packages, and audited 379 packages in 4s

107 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Any ideas what I should be doing here to resolve and get a successful install?

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "main": "./host",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
    "watch": "concurrently --kill-others \"tsc -w\" \"tsc-alias -w\"",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts ./make",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "test": "node host/task/build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.46.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.46.1",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^21.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-exports": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys": "^2.3.5",
    "eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lancejpollard/pretty-compact-json.js": "^0.2.0",
    "chalk": "^5.2.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "source-map": "^0.7.4"
  }
}
```

Now I have `rm -rf node_modules`, and when I do `npm install` again, it shows the same error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Deleting the package-lock.json and the node_modules, and then running npm install solved my issue.

I hope it helps.